# Behaviour of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I have a `asp:TextBox` and I can set the `width` the following way:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

**or**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

In Codebehind I can only set

```
TextBox1.Width = 100; // remember, Width is type of Unit, not int
```

**Not** possible is this:

```
TextBox1.Width = "100%";
```

What I expect

```
TextBox1.Width = new Unit.. ;
```

Question: Why does `nUnit` behave this way? Why is `int` possible but `string` not and why is not a new object of `Unit` expected?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the percentage as this.

```
TextBox1.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(90);
```

Answer (score 0):

TextBox is a `WebControl` where Width is a virtual property defined as:

```
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Unit), "")]
    [WebCategory("Layout")]
    [WebSysDescription("WebControl_Width")]
    public virtual Unit Width
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.ControlStyleCreated)
            {
                return Unit.Empty;
            }
            return this.ControlStyle.Width;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ControlStyle.Width = value;
        }
    }
```

`Unit` is a struct (and this is the answer to your questions):

```
[Serializable]
[TypeConverter(typeof(UnitConverter))]
public struct Unit
{
    internal const int MaxValue = 32767;

    internal const int MinValue = -32768;

    public readonly static Unit Empty;

    private readonly UnitType type;

    private readonly double @value;

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.type == 0;
        }
    }

    public UnitType Type
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.IsEmpty)
            {
                return UnitType.Pixel;
            }
            return this.type;
        }
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.@value;
        }
    }

    static Unit()
    {
        Unit.Empty = new Unit();
    }

    public Unit(int value)
    {
        if (value < -32768 || value > 32767)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        }
        this.@value = (double)value;
        this.type = UnitType.Pixel;
    }

    public Unit(double value)
    {
        if (value < -32768 || value > 32767)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        }
        this.@value = (double)((int)value);
        this.type = UnitType.Pixel;
    }

    public Unit(double value, UnitType type)
    {
        if (value < -32768 || value > 32767)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        }
        if (type != UnitType.Pixel)
        {
            this.@value = value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.@value = (double)((int)value);
        }
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Unit(string value) : this(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, UnitType.Pixel)
    {
    }

    public Unit(string value, CultureInfo culture) : this(value, culture, UnitType.Pixel)
    {
    }

    internal Unit(string value, CultureInfo culture, UnitType defaultType)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            this.@value = 0;
            this.type = (UnitType)0;
            return;
        }
        if (culture == null)
        {
            culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }
        string lower = value.Trim().ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        int length = lower.Length;
        int num = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            char chr = lower[i];
            if ((chr < '0' || chr > '9') && chr != '-' && chr != '.' && chr != ',')
            {
                break;
            }
            num = i;
        }
        if (num == -1)
        {
            object[] objArray = new object[] { value };
            throw new FormatException(SR.GetString("UnitParseNoDigits", objArray));
        }
        if (num >= length - 1)
        {
            this.type = defaultType;
        }
        else
        {
            this.type = Unit.GetTypeFromString(lower.Substring(num + 1).Trim());
        }
        string str = lower.Substring(0, num + 1);
        try
        {
            TypeConverter singleConverter = new SingleConverter();
            this.@value = (double)((float)singleConverter.ConvertFromString(null, culture, str));
            if (this.type == UnitType.Pixel)
            {
                this.@value = (double)((int)this.@value);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            object[] objArray1 = new object[] { value, str, this.type.ToString("G") };
            throw new FormatException(SR.GetString("UnitParseNumericPart", objArray1));
        }
        if (this.@value < -32768 || this.@value > 32767)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Unit))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Unit unit = (Unit)obj;
        if (unit.type == this.type && unit.@value == this.@value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCodeCombiner.CombineHashCodes(this.type.GetHashCode(), this.@value.GetHashCode());
    }

    private static string GetStringFromType(UnitType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case UnitType.Pixel:
            {
                return "px";
            }
            case UnitType.Point:
            {
                return "pt";
            }
            case UnitType.Pica:
            {
                return "pc";
            }
            case UnitType.Inch:
            {
                return "in";
            }
            case UnitType.Mm:
            {
                return "mm";
            }
            case UnitType.Cm:
            {
                return "cm";
            }
            case UnitType.Percentage:
            {
                return "%";
            }
            case UnitType.Em:
            {
                return "em";
            }
            case UnitType.Ex:
            {
                return "ex";
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private static UnitType GetTypeFromString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return UnitType.Pixel;
        }
        if (value.Equals("px"))
        {
            return UnitType.Pixel;
        }
        if (value.Equals("pt"))
        {
            return UnitType.Point;
        }
        if (value.Equals("%"))
        {
            return UnitType.Percentage;
        }
        if (value.Equals("pc"))
        {
            return UnitType.Pica;
        }
        if (value.Equals("in"))
        {
            return UnitType.Inch;
        }
        if (value.Equals("mm"))
        {
            return UnitType.Mm;
        }
        if (value.Equals("cm"))
        {
            return UnitType.Cm;
        }
        if (value.Equals("em"))
        {
            return UnitType.Em;
        }
        if (!value.Equals("ex"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        }
        return UnitType.Ex;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Unit left, Unit right)
    {
        if (left.type != right.type)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return left.@value == right.@value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Unit(int n)
    {
        return Unit.Pixel(n);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Unit left, Unit right)
    {
        if (left.type != right.type)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return left.@value != right.@value;
    }

    public static Unit Parse(string s)
    {
        return new Unit(s, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public static Unit Parse(string s, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Unit(s, culture);
    }

    public static Unit Percentage(double n)
    {
        return new Unit(n, UnitType.Percentage);
    }

    public static Unit Pixel(int n)
    {
        return new Unit(n);
    }

    public static Unit Point(int n)
    {
        return new Unit((double)n, UnitType.Point);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ToString((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public string ToString(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return this.ToString((IFormatProvider)culture);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        string str;
        if (this.IsEmpty)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        str = (this.type != UnitType.Pixel ? ((float)this.@value).ToString(formatProvider) : ((int)this.@value).ToString(formatProvider));
        return string.Concat(str, Unit.GetStringFromType(this.type));
    }
}
```

and it defines a `UnitConverter`:

```
public class UnitConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public UnitConverter()
    {
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string) || destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        string str = value as string;
        if (str == null)
        {
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
        string str1 = str.Trim();
        if (str1.Length == 0)
        {
            return Unit.Empty;
        }
        if (culture != null)
        {
            return Unit.Parse(str1, culture);
        }
        return Unit.Parse(str1, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value == null || ((Unit)value).IsEmpty)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return ((Unit)value).ToString(culture);
        }
        if (destinationType != typeof(InstanceDescriptor) || value == null)
        {
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
        Unit unit = (Unit)value;
        MemberInfo constructor = null;
        object[] objArray = null;
        if (!unit.IsEmpty)
        {
            Type type = typeof(Unit);
            Type[] typeArray = new Type[] { typeof(double), typeof(UnitType) };
            constructor = type.GetConstructor(typeArray);
            object[] objArray1 = new object[] { unit.Value, unit.Type };
            objArray = objArray1;
        }
        else
        {
            constructor = typeof(Unit).GetField("Empty");
        }
        if (constructor == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, objArray);
    }
}
```

In this code you find answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Unit is a struct, if you mean [Unit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx)

- Try myUnit.Value. It will get the value as pointed out.
- You can use [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1sf2c9(v=VS.100).aspx) then `public Unit(int value)` to convert back.

I think this should help.